# How to color the search bar in popup window in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, popup

Okay, so I have this button, which when clicked pulls up a popup with nothing in the window except the address bar. I was wondering if there's some way to color it to possibly make it less noticeable.

Here's my code:

```
<input type="button" onclick="Launch()" value="Launch App">
```

JS:

```
function Launch() {
    window.open("app/intro.html", "winname", "directories = 0, tilebar = 0, toolbar = 0, status = 0, menubar = 0, scrollbars = yes, resizable = yes");
}
```

So is there some hack where you can color the address bar? Or, even better, some way to hide it altogether?

I would love more than anything for it to open in fullscreen, but as far as I know that's not possible. So I was wondering if there was a way just to hide pretty much everything, and the items I cannot hide, just color like a dark blue to match my background, (so that the user can still navigate away from the page if he/she wants to)

Comment: Just to clarify you're asking if it is possible to color/hide the URL Address bar? Pretty sure that's not possible... lots of security issues with that. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe we can find a workaround.

Comment: Well, I have this sort of in-browser emulation, and on the front page I have a "Launch App" button, and when you click the button it opens up a new window with the emulation inside. I would love more than anything for it to open in fullscreen, but as far as I know that's not possible. So I was wondering if there was a way just to hide pretty much everything, and the items I cannot hide, just color like a dark blue to match my background, (so that the user can still navigate away from the page if he/she wants to).

Comment: Does it have to be in Javascript? I went looking and you can do this using the [Fullscreen API](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html). All you would need to do is use javascript to connect it altogether. [Here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/10/Let-Your-Content-Do-the-Talking-Fullscreen-API) is a good tutorial

Comment: Hmm... Looked at it, and it will do. Thanks! :)

Comment: I added it as an answer for now. If you get confused or still need help, just comment :) or if it answered your question, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Fullscreen API](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html) as it might be helpful for you.

Also [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/) has a good tutorial about it [here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/10/Let-Your-Content-Do-the-Talking-Fullscreen-API).

Hope this helps!